# Programa.exe parou de funcionar

Tags: c, string

Estou fazendo um programa que captura o nome completo de uma pessoa e o reproduz nesse formato: sobrenome, nome sem sobrenome (EX:João Carlos Cunha -> Cunha, João Carlos. Amanda Batista -> Batista, Amanda). Só que o usuário pode digitar quantos nome ele quiser, eu tentei limitar até 4, mas o programa para de funcionar.

Não entendo o problema.

Aqui está o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //para usar a função system();

int main(void)
{
int j, i, qntd_palavras=1;
char nomecompleto[100], nome1[20], nome2[20], nome3[20], nome4[20];

do
{
    printf("digite um nome completo\n> "); gets(nomecompleto); fflush(stdin); //pega o nome completo

    for(i=0, j=0;nomecompleto[i]!=' '&&nomecompleto!='\0';i++) //aqui ele pega todos os caracteres do nome completo, até achar um espaço ou o limitador
        nome1[j++] = nomecompleto[i];
    nome1[j]='\0'; //adiciona o limitador no final da string nome1

    if(nomecompleto[i++]=='\0')//aqui é verificado se tem algum outro nome
        break; //se não tiver, o while é cortado

    for(j=0, i++, qntd_palavras++;nomecompleto[i]!=' '&&nomecompleto!='\0';i++)
        nome2[j++] = nomecompleto[i]; //repete o mesmo que no passo 1
    nome2[j]='\0';

    if(nomecompleto[i++]=='\0') //idem
        break; //idem

    for(j=0, i++, qntd_palavras++;nomecompleto[i]!=' '&&nomecompleto!='\0';i++)
        nome3[j++] = nomecompleto[i];
    nome3[j]='\0';

    if(nomecompleto[i++]=='\0')
         break;

   for(j=0, i++, qntd_palavras++;nomecompleto[i]!=' '&&nomecompleto!='\0';i++)
        nome4[j++] = nomecompleto[i];
    nome4[j]='\0';

    if(nomecompleto[i++]==' ') //após quatro palavras, se houver mais alguma, o programa acusa erro e limpa a tela
    {
        printf("\n\nERROR: muitas palavras digitadas!\n\n");
        system("cls || clear");
    }
    else
        break;//se não acusar erro, o laço é terminado
}while(1);

switch(qntd_palavras) //aqui vai decidir como vai ser exibido o nome, dependendo da quantidade de palavras
{
    case 1:printf("\n\n> %s\n\n", nome1);
        break;
    case 2:printf("\n\n> %s, %s", nome2, nome1);
        break;
    case 3:printf("\n\n> %s, %s %s", nome3, nome1, nome2);
        break;
    case 4:printf("\n\n> %s, %s %s %s", nome4, nome1, nome2, nome3);
        break;
    default:break;
}
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
    for(i=0, j=0;nomecompleto[i]!=' '&&nomecompleto!='\0';i++) //aqui ele pega todos os caracteres do nome completo, até achar um espaço ou o limitador
    //                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        nome1[j++] = nomecompleto[i];
```

`nomecompleto` é um array.
Usado na comparação indicada do `for` ele é convertido num apontador para o primeiro elemento.
Esse apontador nunca será `NULL` (ou `'\0'`) e esta parte da condição (`nomecompleto!='\0'`) será sempre verdade o que não é o que esperas.

---

Tenta simplificar a inicialização e condições dos teus ciclos.